# REST API get choice values from column in ascending

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

We are using this URI:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyListName')/fields/getbytitle('MyColumn')
```

to get the choice values from the column.
I need to pull them into an array alphabetically, but the `$orderby.asc` is not working.

Is there a way to get this collection back in alpha ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding there is no direct way to get the choices from choice field in alphabetical order using SharePoint REST API (correct me If I am wrong).

But you can sort the choices after you got the result from REST API using JavaScript. Use `sort()` method like below in success function:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();
```

**Reference**: [JavaScript Array sort() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

This is the code I have used before to achieve the same:

```
$.ajax({
    url: <siteUrl> + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Internal Name'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var choicesArray = [];
        if(data && data.d.results) {
            choicesArray = data.d.results[0].Choices.results.sort();
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

You can get the internal name of your choice column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Update**:

You can also sort the array in Microsoft Flow/Power automate. Please check below links for possible solution.

1. [Sort an array in Power Automate in 3 easy steps](https://sharepains.com/2020/03/05/sort-an-array-in-power-automate/)
2. [How to implement Sort with Microsoft Flow in 3 actions within a loop](http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/12/how-to-implement-sort-with-microsoft-flow-in-3-actions-within-a-loop)

Comment: Thank you...we are using Microsoft PowerAutomate for this REST call.  I don't know if JavaScript is an option...will need to look into

Comment: What are you doing after getting this choices using flow? Binding these values to dropdown in PowerApps? Or just using in flow only?

Comment: Just finished the flow using https://sharepains.com/2020/03/05/sort-an-array-in-power-automate/...thank you!

Comment: Great I am updating my answer for the same. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.