# SharePoint Online Display All Options in a Choice Field In A Custom Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

Is there a way to fetch all the Choice Options of a Choice Field created in a SharePoint Online List and to display in a custom SharePoint Page(Inside Pages Library/Site Pages)?(Without the help of any web parts).

I am creating a Poll with graphical representation using JQuery and JavaScript.

I need to display Poll questions in a custom made page.

The questions of the Poll should come from a SharePoint list and the options(Answer list of the Poll) would be fetched from a choice field say Radio button type from the same list. All the choice field options should be displayed for the users to select while participating in the poll.

Comment: How are you adding JS/jQuery to modern page or are you using classic pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using JavaScript and jQuery, you can use SharePoint REST API to fetch the choices/options from choice column in SharePoint list.

You have to use the REST endpoint like:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq '<Choice Field Internal Name>'
```

Where `<Choice Field Internal Name>` is the internal name of your choice column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Check below threads for complete code:

1. [I am trying to get the choice type field value in select tag from SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/295520/i-am-trying-to-get-the-choice-type-field-value-in-select-tag-from-sharepoint-lis/295524#295524)
2. [REST API get choice values from column in ascending](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280466/rest-api-get-choice-values-from-column-in-ascending/280469#280469)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, It worked! I am able to fetch all options from choice field. Great help! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!